# Two prepositions used one after the other without conjunction?

Tags: prepositions

Example (I saw it on some page)

> So, you can see that we need a conjunction **to for** the sentence to be clear!

Which of the following are rewritten correctly?

1. So, you can see that we need **a conjunction to the sentence for the sentence to be clear**!
2. So, you can see that we need **the sentence a conjunction for the sentence to be clear**!
3. So, you can see that we need **a conjunction to and for the sentence to be clear**!

In the first two examples I repeated one words two times. In the third - just a conjunction.

Is there a rule? I think in the example word sentence is dropped!

Comment: "So, you can see that we need a conjunction for the sentence to be clear!" is all that seems needed.

Comment: Neither the original nor any of the rewrites is grammatical or makes any sense at all. _To_ simply has nothing to do in that sentence; get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

The original is arguably valid but very strange and hard to read. There lies ambiguity in the prepositional phrase of *to*. My interpretation is that it makes an omission like so:

> So, you can see that we need a conjunction to **[the sentence]** for the sentence to be clear!

Which gives us (1), which is correct but I would prefer to use a pronoun in place of the second *"the sentence"*:

> So, you can see that we need a conjunction to the sentence for **it** to be clear!

The same goes for (2), which I think is clearer than the original but still doesn't read well. I interpret (2) as making an omission like so:

> So, you can see that we need the sentence **[to have]** a conjunction for **it** to be clear!

It's as if (3) is trying to fix the original but ends up making it worse because it removes no ambiguity whatsoever, while introducing the conjunction *'and'* that really shouldn't be there, further fueling the reader's confusion.

If I could rephrase the whole sentence, I'd write

> So, you can see that the sentence needs a conjunction for it to be clear.

Comment: Do you really prefer #2 to #1? If so, how do you parse "the sentence a conjunction" as the thing said to be needed?

Comment: I totally agree with you with the first two examples, but don't get why isn't correct the third?
But why the author wrote so? As I understand he is native, but his sentence written in such way?! After prep phrase usually goes object of prep phrase, but in the origanal after prep goes prep and then objects of prep or is it correct when prep phrase is a object of prep?

Comment: in the second example "the sentence" is an indirect object.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain why (3) makes the original sentence more confusing and arguably invalid.

Comment: I updated my answer again to explain how I parsed (2).

Answer (score 0):

> So, you can see that we need a conjunction **to** for the sentence to be clear!

This makes no sense, and is most likely a typo for:

> So, you can see that we need a conjunction **too** for the sentence to be clear!

("Too" means "also" or "as well".)

Alternatively, you can delete word "to" altogether.